# Diagram doesn't show in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, diagram

I have a Shiny application that shows the relationship between race and number of employees in Silicon Valley companies. The toolbar on the left side is visible but the plot is not showing. How should I change my code?

Here is the code:

```
 library(shiny)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(dplyr)

 bcl <- read.csv("E:/country/data/reveal.csv")

 ui <- fluidPage(
 titlePanel("Silicon valley"),
 sidebarLayout(
 sidebarPanel(
 sliderInput("countInput", "count", 0, 100, c(25, 40)),
 radioButtons("jobInput", "Job category",
              choices = c("Technicians", "Professionals", "Sales workers", "Administrative support"),
              selected = "Technicians"),
 selectInput("companyInput", "company",
              choices = c("Twitter", "Uber", "View"))
),
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("coolplot"),
  br(), br(),
  tableOutput("results")
)
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
output$coolplot <- renderPlot({
filtered <-
  bcl %>%
  filter(count == input$countInput,
         job_category == input$jobInput,
         company == input$companyInput
  )
ggplot(filtered, aes(race)) +
  geom_histogram()
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Instead of posting a picture of the data, please use the `dput` function in R. Post the data in your question. A subset of the data is usually fine.

Comment: Write `?dput` in the R console to open up the Help pages.

Comment: Paste the output from `dput` in your question. Never post data as pictures since it cannot be copied. Please remove them and use `dput`.

Comment: ok, but my data has 3960 records

Comment: Then use a subset or make it available on Dropbox or something.

Comment: I've added the link to data in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

bcl <- read.csv(file = "reveal.csv", colClasses = c("character", "integer", "factor", "factor", "factor", "integer"), na.strings = c("na", "NA")) %>% na.omit()

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Silicon valley"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    sliderInput("countInput", "count", 0, 100, c(0, 100)),
                    radioButtons(
                      "jobInput",
                      "Job category",
                      choices = c(
                        "Technicians",
                        "Professionals",
                        "Sales workers",
                        "Administrative support"
                      ),
                      selected = "Technicians"
                    ),
                    selectInput("companyInput", "company",
                                choices = c("Twitter", "Uber", "View"))
                  ),
                  mainPanel(plotOutput("coolplot"),
                            br(), br(),
                            tableOutput("results"))
                ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$coolplot <- renderPlot({
    filtered <-
      bcl %>%
      filter(
        count == input$countInput,
        job_category == input$jobInput,
        company == input$companyInput
      )
    ggplot(filtered, aes(race)) +
      geom_bar()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have changed `geom_histogram` to `geom_bar` since it is a better option for your data. Let me know what you think.

Comment: thank you, it works, but it seems that I should modify code a little, because it doesn't work correctly if I change company or change job category

Comment: Exactly, there are a couple of things to keep working on :-) Keep coding!